# Detecting scoll to bottom of div different for different users of same PC

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome

This is really strange. I have the following JavaScript on a page to detect when a user has scrolled to the bottom of a div:

```
var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
if (div.scrollHeight - div.scrollTop === div.clientHeight) {
    window.location = 'page2.aspx';
}
```

The functionality works fine on the various browsers I tested. However, it isn't working in Chrome on one of my colleague's computer (although it is working for her in IE). So I went to test on her computer using my own Windows login (I believe we use Active Directory; I have elevated permissions, she doesn't). When I tested it on Chrome, it worked. But when I logged off and she logged in and tested it, it didn't (I verified it).

Can you think of any explanation for this behavior?

TIA.

Comment: zoom levels, multi-monitor pref, OS font size, toolbar extensions, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm investigating zoom levels now. I can now reproduce the issue on my own PC using zoom levels, but my colleague isn't zoomed in or out on the page in question.